# How to calculate numbers in a list?

Tags: python, list

I have to add every number with one behind it in the list using loops or functions

example text;

```
list[1,2,3] => (1+3)+(2+1)+(3+2)
```

output = 12

example code;

```
myList = [1,2,3]
x = myList [0] + myList [2]
x = x + (myList [1]+myList [0])
x = x + (myList [2]+myList [1])
print(x) # 12
```

I dont want to calculate them using `sum() or just like 1+2+3`

Comment: @PM77-1 Why a nested loop?

Comment: This is just twice the sum of the list, because additional is associative.

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes, I don't see anything about uniqueness, it's just summying `myList[i] + myList[i-1]`.

Comment: @Bamar - then you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the list, adding the element and the element before it to the total. Since list indexing wraps around when the index is negative, this will treat the last element as before the first element.

```
total = 0
for i in range(len(myList)):
    total += myList[i] + myList[i-1]
print(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, `list[-1]` returns the last element of the list so doing something like this should do the job -

```
myList = [1,2,3]
total = 0
for i, num in enumerate(myList):
    print(num, myList[i-1])
    total += num + myList[i-1]
print(total)
```

Output:

```
1 3
2 1
3 2
12
```

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the list index and value using enumerate function

```
>>> [x+mylist[i-1] for i, x in enumerate(mylist)]
[4, 3, 5]
```

To get the sum of the result

```
>>> sum([x+mylist[i-1] for i, x in enumerate(mylist)])
12
```

Comment: Where is the total in this?